# How to I import "colorama" libary into python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, colorama

**I have been experiencing major problems when Importing and trying to use modules like colorama or colored**

I have Python 3.10 installed (final version) and have already typed these commands into cmd (also while being in the python path)

```sh
pip install colorama
pip3 install colorama
python3 pip install colorama
```

(everything installed perfectly)

I dont know if thats normal but when looking into the libs folder there is no module. Also after uninstalling and installing the module again.

this is what it say in Visual Studio

```
reportMi: Import "colorama" could not be resolved from source
```

also

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning (active)    reportMissingModuleSource   Import "colorama" could not be resolved from source     "the direction"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if Colorama is installed in the correct location by typing the command `pip install colorama` in the cmd:
[image]

After which you can import it like so:

```py
from colorama import init, Fore, Back


#init colorama
init()
```

Hope you found this helpful.

Comment: Well thats not the problem.
It just wouldnt import, no matter what I did.